# sudo apt-get install not working

Tags: apt

I was installing Chrome using `apt-get` and after that I'm not able use command
`sudo apt-get install`  or `sudo apt-get update`
anything which I am doing with my package manager is not working, is always showing this error:

```
Reading package lists...Error! 
E: Problem parsing dependency Recommends    
E: Error occurred while processing foomatic-filters (NewVersion2)    
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/dpkg/status    
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

Can you please tell me how to fix this problem? I am using Ubuntu 11.10. I am not even able to upgrade to Ubuntu 12.04 because of this problem.

Comment: This is OT, not a dulplicated.

Comment: I think there is nothing wrong with pointing the older duplicate. More friendly and understandable to newbies?

Answer (score 1):

You should also be able to upgrade normally, following [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/91821/178596). This may also help resolve some `dpkg` errors.

As an alternative, since this is such an old version, and now [End Of Life](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases), it may be easier to [download an `.iso`](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) image, put it on [a dvd](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-ubuntu) or [USB stick](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu), and install 12.04 over it. This will be easy if you have a separate `/home` partition, as Ubuntu should be able to replace 11.10 with 12.04, but leave your users files alone.

Make a full backup of all your data first. You may also find [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-old-unsupported-release) helpful.

Comment: I would just upgrade from the dvd/usb since he got 11.10 and the next version is 12.04. this is the way to do it if you have /home in the same partition as the rest..

Comment: ohk...i had this method in mind but can't we fix this problem without reinstalling ubuntu i.e. upgrading it with a dvd or USB stick..?
i have been searching ubuntu forms to fix this but had no sucess!!

Comment: See Alvar's link, if you insist on running on old software without security updates you can probably do the reading which tells you how. @askubuntu the policy is not to support EOL versions.